# How to make text iterate with the categories array

Tags: css, arrays, zendesk

In Zendesk's help center, there is the use of handlebar.js arrays.

I haven't found a way to access them other than calling them using the handlebar syntax.

I want to add icons too this array, in a way that a different icon is used based on the name of the category.
Here is my snippet of code:

```
{{#each categories}}
        <li>
          <!-- Catergories Array -->
          <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap fa-4x" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-top:30px;"> </i>
          <p>
          <a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
            </li>
      {{/each}}
```

Here you can see the categories array is called, where and it is put into a new line. I have added the font awesome graduation cap which I want to use for the tutorials category I created in the editor.

On line 6, links are called in relation to the position in the array. The url and the name iterate together. I however cannot add a font awesome symbol to the name, nor can I have it iterate by putting it outside of the double curlybars.

I looked in the javascript and in the CSS and there is no reference to Categories where I can modify data elements of the array (otherwise I could easily add an icon element).

Does anyone have experience with creating custom zendesk Help Centers?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question, but can you turn the name into the html necessary to display the icon?
`[{url: foo, name: bar}, {url: foo1, name: '<i class="fa my-icon"></i>'}]`

If this does not work, you can add a bool to your object that indicates if the element of the array contains an icon instead of a name, and conditionally change the html displayed.

```
{{#if is_icon}}
  <a href="{{url}}"><i class="{{icon-class}}"></i></a>
{{else}}
  <a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
{{/if}}
```